# How to get the bytecode of a transaction using the solidity-browser?

Tags: solidity, remix, myetherwallet

I want to get the **bytecode** to put in the **"MyEtherWallet/Send-Ether"** when I want to make some transaction, sending some ether to some contract, to call some function in the contract. I **need** to use the "**Solidity-Browser**" to this end.

Answer (score 3):

The bytecode is provided in [browser-solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) compiler, just check the interface at the right :

[image]

you could decode the bytecode to the opcodes using : https://etherscan.io/opcode-tool

**Edit** : New Remix
press details button then copy the bytecode from the popup as follows:

[image]

Comment: Is this also showing on https://remix.ethereum.org/ ? Because if yes I don't see it

Comment: yes but the screenshot was of an old remix version. i've updated my answer

Comment: Oh thanks. So this is the contract bytecode with args used right?

Comment: think of upvoting if it was helpfull