# Where is the Ethereum Virtual Machine Code available?

Tags: solidity, evm

In this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/21137/84678) is explained how to see EVM instructions doing reverse engineer.

But, where is the code available?

On Ethereum github's account there are a bunch of evm projects, but it is not clear which is the actual EVM being used by the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The go-to implementation that I use is the one included in go-ethereum available [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/core/vm).

As it is part of the most used Ethereum client, I believe it is safe to assume that it is amongst the most up-to-date implementations.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, the link is not working, could you update it?

Comment: Just fixed it, my bad !

Answer (score 1):

Each client implements the evm.
Different clients exists in different languages.
Check each client GitHub repos for instance https://github.com/hyperledger/besu/tree/main/evm/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/besu/evm for the Besu client.